# DevExpress GroupRow - get information about DataRows belonging to that GroupRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

If I group my Grid by some parameter, is there any method that would return to me, let's say, a List of names of all the elements in that group. 
e.g. I have a grid of Cars and I group them by country. And then I click on "Germany" GroupRow. Is there any function that I could put on some button, for example "Export selected cars" that would return to me all the car names from that GroupRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be only obtained using the server code.  For example:

```
List<object> GetGroupNames(int groupRowVisibleIndex){
  List<object> result = new List<string>();
  int childCount = ASPxGridView1.GetChildRowCount(groupRowIndex);

  for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i ++)  
    result.Add(ASPxGridView1.GetChildRowValues(groupRowVisibleIndex, i, "CarName"));
}
```

Here is the link to documentation where you will find descriptions to all methods I used in this code:

[ASPxGridView members](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewMembersTopicAll)